# Pointer to incompatible class type is not allowed (pass struct by pointer)

Tags: c

I have such struct

```
struct Request
{
    char *command;
    char firstSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char secondSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char resultSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    int input[sizeof(int) * 4];
};
```

And such a method

```
int parseToReadRequest(char * command, struct Request * request)
{
    printf("Command is : %s\n", command);
    strcpy(request->firstSetName, "dddd");   <---- It this line I get an error
    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error in line that I marked above

> Pointer to incompatible class type is not allowed

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have commented on this line

```
struct Request
{
    char *command;
    char firstSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char secondSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char resultSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    /*int input[sizeof(int) * 4];*/    <---- This
};
```

And anyway I get an error on this line

```
int parseToReadRequest(char * command, struct Request * request)
{
    printf("Command is : %s\n", command);
    strcpy(request->firstSetName, "ddd");   <--- This
    return 0;
}
```

> parcer.c:7:19: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct Request'
>       strcpy(request->firstSetName, "ddd");

Comment: What compiler are you using? It looks like a C++ error, not C.

Comment: I suspect you haven't actually `#include`d the definition header for the struct. Without the definition, C will take `struct Request` as an incomplete declaration, which means you can manipulate the pointer (basically pass it to children that do have the declaration or store it), but you can't access members.

Comment: @GemTaylor yes, I really forgot. I am working in `.c` file, but I forgot to include his `.h` file where this struct header was included... stupid mistake. Anyway thanks, you can post this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't actually #included the definition header for the struct. Without the definition, C will take struct Request as an incomplete declaration, which means you can manipulate the pointer (basically pass it to children that do have the declaration or store it), but you can't access members.

This is why you generally see the typedef thing so the struct keyword is not required and the error occurs earlier.